# How do I enable the Java console in Firefox?

Tags: leopard, firefox, java

I'm using MacOSX 10.5.8 and the default Java provided by Apple (e.g. /usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java). My web browser is Firefox 3.6.12.

I'd like to view the Java console to debug some Java applets which I access with Firefox.

How can I enable the Java console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not done via any Firefox configuration option, but an account wide Java setting:

Open the **Java Preferences** utility which you can find in Applications -> Utilities.

There, under the Advanced tab, and "Java console", choose "Show console".
[image]

Comment: I have tried this, and I still do not see a console. I believe that the console may be active, but does not automatically become visible when I open a Java applet.

Comment: Well, eventually this did work. I had to change "Run applets:" back to the default "Within Browser Process', and now the console works. I did try both options before, and neither worked.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the "Run applets" setting, but glad you got it working :)